# Error while migrating jsf 1.2 to 2.0

Tags: java, jsf, migration, weblogic-10.x

I want to migrate JSF version and used this url as a reference [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

Changes in my view file to

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:sf="http://www.springframework.org/tags/faces"
    xmlns:fmt="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags">

   faces-config file changed as:

    <faces-config version="2.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">
```

But while deploying my application in weblogic. 
I am getting the following error

> User defined listener com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener failed: java.lang.RuntimeException:com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED!javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory. java.lang.RuntimeException:com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:287) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1801) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3045) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1397) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:54) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) Caused By: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:357) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:219) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1801) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3045) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1397) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:54) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173) Caused By: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerFactory at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.validateFactoryName(FactoryFinder.java:578) at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.setFactory(FactoryFinder.java:264) at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.setFactory(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:283) at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.processFactories(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:239) at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:193) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:338) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:219) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121) at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1801) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3045) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1397) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:460) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:83) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409) at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:54) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:181) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:12) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:67) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:516) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

Can you please help us where we are wrong or what needs to be done..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: So, what changes did you do before the error raised?

Comment: i have added jsf, impl 2.0 jars and removed facelets.jar from my application, changed servlet version to 2.5 in web.xml and changed xsd def version to 2.0 in faces-config. I have not changes any beans because I am using spring to manage beans.
Is there anything else to change @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Are those the only messages in your stacktrace, nothing more?

Answer (score 1):

Look the blog post from Mkyong:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-javax-faces-context-exceptionhandlerfactory/

The fact is that you are using Weblogic, no Tomcat, but the cause of the problem could be the same: Weblogic is picking a JSF 1.2 API instead of the new JSF 2.0 API, in the `javaee.jar`. Remove that file from the project's classpath, than clean project on your server, and redeploy it. I hope that will help!